# How can I divide number into each digit (example) 11 = xy, x=1, y1

Tags: javascript, jquery, numbers

I have following object

```
var obj = { b0: 11, b1: 12
            b3: 21, b4: 22 }
```

I need separate digits and give look like coordinates (for future manipulation) to each one when first digit is `x` and second `y`. And mb when if `(x1==x2 && y2-y1==1) =` do some event

Comment: you can use http://jsfiddle.net for demo

Answer (score 1):

If numbers are only ever gonna be two digits, you could dosomething like this:

```
function somesome() {
    var obj = { b0: 11, b1: 12, b3: 21, b4: 22 }
    var current = obj.b1
        console.log(current.toString().substring(0,1)); //first number
        console.log(current.toString().substring(1,2)); //second number
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

```
var obj = { 'b0': 11, 'b1': 12, 'b3': 21, 'b4': 22 },
    matrixData = {}; 

for (var key in obj) {
    var sNum = obj[key].toString(),
        output = {'x': sNum.charAt(0),'y': sNum.charAt(1) };
    matrixData[key] = output;
}

console.log(matrixData);
```

You receive a nested object with your x and y coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

You could call the SStrings prototype method `split` and return an array of numbers again, something like this

```
function splitNumber (n) {
    var arr = String.prototype.split.call(n,"");
    var narr = [];
    for (var i=0,ilen = arr.length;i<ilen;i++)
        narr[i] = Number(arr[i])
    return narr
}
var x = 11
splitNumber(x) // [1,1]
```